# Prove if $f'(1)$ is Real then $f'(1)\ge 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

While Solving exams of previous years I encountered this problem which I cannot solve

Prove if $f'(1)$ is Real then $f'(1)\ge 1$,

Let $f$ be holomorphic(has a derivative) at $\Omega = \{|z|<1\}\cup\{|z-1|<r\}$ for some $r>0$.

Assume:

- $f(0)=0$
- $f(1)=1$
- $\forall z\in\Omega \space(|z|<1 \implies |f(z)|<1)$

Anyway I try to look at it... I don't get anywhere :\

Thanks

Comment: What are exactly the assumptions of the problem? $f(z)=\frac{z}{2}$ is a trivial counterexample to the question in the title.

Comment: @Wojowu: Your example does not satisfy $f(1)=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ maps the unit disk into itself with $f(0) = 0$, so from the
[Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) it follows that
$$ 
  |f(z)| \le |z| \text{ for } |z| < 1 \, .
$$
In particular,
$$
 \DeclareMathOperator {\re}{Re}
 \re f(r) \le |f(r)| \le r \text{ for } 0 < r < 1 \, .
$$

$f'(1)$ is a real number and $f(1)=1$, therefore
$$
 f'(1) = \re f'(1) = 
\re \left( \lim_{r \to 1-}  \frac{f(1)-f(r)}{1-r} \right) \\ =
\lim_{r \to 1-} \re \left (\frac{f(1)-f(r)}{1-r} \right) =
 \lim_{r \to 1-} \frac{1 - \re f(r)}{1-r} \ge 1 \, .
$$