# Prove $f'(1)\ge 0$ when $f$ holomorphic in $B(0,1)\cup \left\{ 1 \right\}$ and $f(1)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $f$ be a function holomorphic in $B(0,1)\cup \left\{ 1 \right\}$ with 
>   $$f(B(0,1))\subset B(0,1),\ \ f(1)=1$$
>   Prove that $f'(1)\ge 0$.

My attempt: I have tried to find some property of $f$ when $f'(1)\neq 0$, and guessed if I can prove $\operatorname{arg}f'(1)=0$, but don't know how to proceed specifically. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have a look at the first part of http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1953895/42969, where it is shown that $f'(1) = u_x(1)$.

Comment: @MartinR one more question: why $\exists r>0$ such that $f$ analytic on $B(0,1)\cup D(1,r)$?

Comment: $f$ being holomorphic at $\left\{ 1 \right\}$ means that it is holomorphic in a small neighbourhood of that point. Holomorphy is only defined on open sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof based only on the existence of derivative in the sense that
$$
f'(1) = \lim_{z\to 1,\ z\in B(0,1)}\frac{f(z)-f(1)}{z-1}
$$
exists. For every $\theta \in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ the point $1-re^{i\theta}$ lies in $B(0,1)$ when $r>0$ is small enough. By the definition of derivative,
$$
f(1-re^{i\theta}) = 1 - f'(1) re^{i\theta} + o(r),\qquad r\to 0
$$
Since $|f|<1$, the real part of $1 - f'(1) re^{i\theta}$ cannot exceed $1$; this implies $\operatorname{Re}(f'(1) e^{i\theta})\ge 0$. Writing $f'(1)$ in polar coordinates, $f'(1) = \rho e^{it}$, makes it clear that $t=0$, for otherwise $\exp(i(t+\theta))$ has negative real part for some $\theta\in (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.