$f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and satisfies $|f(z)| \leq|f(1)|$ whenever $|z|<1$
Let $\Omega$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, containing the disk $D=\{z \in$ $\mathbb{C}:|z| \leq 1\}$. Assume that $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is analytic and satisfies $|f(z)| \leq|f(1)|$ whenever $|z|<1$. I would like to show  $f^{\prime}(1) \neq 0$, unless $f$ is constant.
If $f(1)=0$, then $f \equiv 0$ in $\Omega$ since it vanishes identically on $D$ and $\Omega$ is connected, hence a constant. If not, $g(z)=f(z)/f(1)$ is analytic and $g: D \to \overline{D}$. In fact, unless $f$ is constant, we can have $g:D\to D$. At this point, I tried to use Schwarz-Pick but it didn't help. I believe the argument should be by contradiction, but I'm having trouble closing the proof.

a fairly simple argument is using the local form; assume $f'(1)=0$ so near $1$ we have $f(z)=f(1)+b(z-1)^k+o((z-1)^k), k \ge 2$; wlog assume $f(1)>0$ by possibly multiplying $f$ with a modulus $1$ constant; for small enough $\epsilon$ we have that the domain $|w-1|< \epsilon, |w| <1$ is sent by $w \to (w-1)^k$ to cover close to a full small disc around $1$ since $k \ge 2$; in particular one can find such $w$ so $\arg \bar b-\arg (w-1)^k$ is small enough; then $b(w-1)^k$ is almost positive - for example one can guarantee that its real part is strictly positive - hence $|f(w)| >|f(1)|$

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167111/prove-f1-ge-0-when-f-holomorphic-in-b0-1-cup-left-1-right-and?noredirect=1 maybe help you!

Consider non-constant $h(z):=\frac{f\big(\frac{1}{z}\big)}{f(1)}$; it suffices to show that $h'(1)\neq 0$ and in particular that the winding number $ n\big(h\circ \gamma,1\big)\lt 2$ for $\gamma: \big[\frac{-1}{4},\frac{3}{4} \big]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by $\gamma(t):=1+ r\cdot\exp\big(2\pi i \cdot t\big)$ for $r\gt 0$ small enough.  Geometrically if you restrict to the first half of this curve, the image under $h$ is constrained to the unit disc necessarily doing $\lt \frac{1}{2}$ of a revolution around $1$ which implies $n\big(h\circ \gamma,1\big)\lt 2$.

I gave the details to support that geometric claim under part (ii) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688731/a-complex-analysis-proof-of-the-extremal-case-of-bernsteins-inequality/  (the problem is different but the roles of $\gamma$ and $h$ are identical and really all that needs to be followed)

This question is similar to: The derivative of a holomorphic function on the boundary of the unit circle. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've tagged this as a duplicate as OP has reduced the problem to non-constant $g:\overline {\mathbb D} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb D}$ but $m\circ g: \overline {\mathbb D}\longrightarrow \overline{\mathbb D}$ and sends $0$ to $0$ and $1$ to $1$ for suitable moebius map $m$.  The link show $\frac{d}{dz} (m\circ g) \neq 0$ at $z=1$ which implies $\frac{d}{dz} g \neq 0$ at $z=1$ by the chain rule.
