Pole of positive real function on the imaginary axis
Added following user8675309's comments below: A rational polynomial, $H(s)$, with real coefficients is called positive real if $\Re(s) \ge 0 \implies \Re(H(s)) \ge 0$ (except for poles of $H(s)$ on the imaginary axis where $\Re(H(s))$ is not defined).

I am wondering about the possibility of using the argument principle to prove the following well-known property of such a function.

It can have no pole in the open right half plane.
Any pole on the imaginary axis must be simple and must have a real positive residue.

This is usually proved in textbooks on circuit theory (like this one) using the logic that near a pole $p$ of multiplicity $m$, the function looks like $\frac{A}{(s-p)^m}$.
I am curious if this can be proved instead using the argument principle.
(1) is easy to prove: Suppose $H(s)$ has a pole $p$ of multiplicity $m$ in the open right half plane. Consider a closed contour in the open right half plane encircling this pole, but no other poles and zeros. By the argument principle, the argument of $H(s)$ changes by $-2\pi m$ as $s$ traverses this contour. Then the sign of $\Re(H(s))$ changes $2m$ times, meaning that it takes on negative values. Thus $H(s)$ is not positive real, which is a contradiction.
I am however not sure how to prove (2). Suppose $H(s)$ has a pole $p$ of multiplicity $m$ on the imaginary axis. Again consider a contour encircling this pole, but no other poles and zeros. There are again $2m$ sign changes in $\Re(H(s))$. What I am not sure how to get around is what if all these sign changes occur as $s$ traverses the part of the contour that is in the left half plane.

Edit after user8675309's comments below: My exact question then is if (2) can somehow be proved using the argument principle.

If $H(s)$ has a pole on the imaginary axis, doesn't $H(s-1)$ have a pole on the right half-plane?  (and if $H(s)$ is positive real, so is $H(s-1)$...)

@Eric Towers It is not true that is $H(s)$ is real, so is $H(s-1)$. For example $H(s)=\frac{1}{s+0.5}$ is positive real, but $H(s-1)=\frac{1}{s-0.5}$ is not. The other way is true, if $H(s-1)$ is positive real, so is $H(s)$, but not sure is that plays a role in my question.

@user8675309 The definition of positive real function I am going by is "$s$ real $\implies H(s)$ real; $\Re(s)\ge 0 \implies \Re(H(s)) \ge 0$". Is the $\gamma$ you are referring to not closed? I will read your proof in the link. Are you referring to the part about winding number of a non-closed curve?

What if I kept that definition and restricted to $H(s)$ being a rational polynomial?

a rational function or really anything meromorphic on $\mathbb C$ will do but at the end of the day it is your function so you should supply the definitiion

The functions I am interested in are transfer functions of dynamic systems, so rational functions make sense. I will edit the question with my definition.

The part (ii.) in my link still is how I'd argue this.  I think most people are not comfortable using winding numbers of non-closed curves hence are uncomfortable with the Key Lemma used.  If you are ok with the Key Lemma I can fill in the details with how it gives the result here.

by the way your problem is $H:\mathbb C_\infty \longrightarrow \mathbb C_\infty\cong S^2$ where $H$ maps the closed right hemisphere into itself.  Neither $H$ nor $\frac{1}{H}$ can have a zero in the open right hemishphere do to the open mapping theorem.  If you rotate suitably this turns into a question about a non-constant (rational) $f$ that maps the closed unit disc to itself and why if $\vert f(1)\vert =1$ then $f'(1)\neq 0$, i.e. this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4958549/f-omega-to-mathbbc-is-analytic-and-satisfies-fz-leqf1-wheneve

To the first of your most recent two comments, I am ok with the Key Lemma. Winding number of a non-closed curve doesn't bother me since I can equivalently think of the argument change from $\gamma(a)$ to $\gamma(b)$ and from $\sigma(a)$ to $\sigma(b)$. Is this thinking right? It will be great if you could fill in the details for how this can be used to prove (2) above. PS: what does the $\text{Arg}_{-\pi}$ notation in the proof the Key Lemma mean?

To the second of your two most recent comments, I see the mappings, how a Mobius transformation $z=T(s)$ would take the right half plane (hemisphere) to the unit circle, and $f(z)=H(T^{-1}(z))$. But I don't see the connection to $|f(1)|=1$ and $f'(1)=0$.

The question is about a non-constant meromorphic (in fact rational) function $H$ defined on $\mathbb C$ that sends the closed right half plane into itself (except at poles).  Notice that $\frac{1}{H}$ and $H\big(z-t\cdot i\big)$ for any $t\in \mathbb R$ also have this property, so when investigating poles on the imaginary line, we may assume WLOG the pole occurs at $z=0$ and set $F:=\frac{1}{H}$.  The technique is to bound the winding number of a closed curve by looking at half of said curve and estimating the winding number for that non-closed curve using the Key Lemma from the end of  A complex analysis proof of the extremal case of Bernstein's inequality?
Define $\gamma: \big[\frac{-1}{4},\frac{3}{4} \big]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by $\gamma(t):=r\cdot\exp\big(2\pi i \cdot t\big)$ for $r\gt 0$ small enough.  Application of the Argument Principle tells us
$0\leq k =n\Big(F\circ \gamma,0\Big)$
$F(z)= z^k\cdot g(z)$ and $q(z) := z^k\cdot \lambda$
where $g(z)$ is an analytic function that is locally non-zero and $g(0)=\lambda \in \mathbb C-\big\{0\big\}$. And since re-scaling a function by a positive number does not change the winding number (e.g. based on definitions or application of the Argument Principle) we can assume WLOG that $\vert \lambda \vert =1$
Now with $a:=\frac{-1}{4}$ and $b:=\frac{1}{4}$ we may apply the linked Key Lemma with $\gamma_1(t):=F\circ \gamma_{\big\vert [a,b]}$ and $\sigma_1(t):=q\circ \gamma_{\big\vert [a,b]}$.
In words: we restrict $\gamma$ to the counter clockwise rotation from $-r\cdot i$ to $r\cdot i$, which lies in the closed right half plane, and compose with $h$ and $q$ respectively.  To be clear, with $w:=0$, for any $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ continuity of $g$ tells us there is a $\delta \gt 0$ such that for all $r\in(0,\delta)$ we have, for arbitrary $t\in [a,b]$
$\Big \vert \gamma_1(t)-\sigma_1(t)\Big \vert =\Big \vert z^k\cdot g(z)-z^k\cdot \lambda\Big \vert = \Big\vert z\Big\vert^k\cdot \Big \vert g(z) -\lambda\Big \vert$
$\lt \epsilon \cdot \vert z \vert^k\cdot \Big \vert \lambda\Big \vert = \epsilon \cdot \Big \vert \sigma_1(t)-w\big \vert $
And selecting $\epsilon:=\frac{\pi}{4+\pi}$ gives
$ \frac{k}{2}-\Big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, 0\big)\Big \vert$
$ \leq \Big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, 0\big)-\frac{k}{2}\Big \vert= \Big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, 0\big)-n\big(\sigma_1,0\big)\Big \vert = \Big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, w\big)-n\big(\sigma_1,w\big)\Big \vert $
$\lt \frac{ \left(\frac{\pi}{4+\pi}\right)}{\pi\cdot\left(1-(\frac{\pi}{4+\pi})\right)}=\frac{1}{4}\text{ (Key Lemma in link)}$
$\implies \frac{k}{2}\lt \Big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, 0\big)\Big \vert + \frac{1}{4} \leq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} \lt 1\implies k \lt 2$
where the key step is that $\big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, 0\big)\big \vert \leq \frac{1}{2}$
because the curve is contained in the (closed) right half plane hence it winds around zero at most $\frac{1}{2}$ of a time.  This follows from the definition of the winding number but can be interpreted in terms of $I5$ in Chapter 7 of Beardon's Complex Analysis: since $\gamma_1$ does not meet $\mathbb R_{\leq 0}$ we can use $\text{Arg}_{-\pi}$ --the standard argument function taking values in $(-\pi, \pi)$ from the logarithm defined on the slit plane $\mathbb C-\mathbb R_{\leq 0}$-- as a choice of branch so $\Big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, 0\big)\Big \vert = \left \vert\frac{\text{Arg}_{-\pi}(\gamma(b))-\text{Arg}_{-\pi}(\gamma(a))}{2\pi}\right\vert\leq \left \vert\frac{\text{Arg}_{-\pi}(\gamma(b))}{2\pi}\right\vert+\left \vert\frac{\text{Arg}_{-\pi}(\gamma(a))}{2\pi}\right\vert \leq 2\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{2}\pi}{2\pi}=\frac{1}{2}$.
Conclude:
$0\leq k =n\Big(F\circ \gamma,0\Big)\lt 2\implies n\Big(F\circ \gamma,0\Big)\in \Big\{0,1\Big\}$ so if $H$ has a pole at zero then it must be simple.
addendum re: the residue
if $H\big(0\big)=\infty$ then $0$
is a simple pole as the above degree argument shows.  Writing out the Laurent expansion of $H$ in $\big\{z: 0 \lt \vert z\vert\lt \delta\big\}$ for $\delta\gt 0$ small enough we have
$H\big(z\big) =a_{-1}\cdot z^{-1} + a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^{2}+\dots$ where $a_{-1}\neq 0$ since it is a simple pole.
The goal is to show $a_{-1}\in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}$.  It is immediate that $a_{-1}$ is in the closed right half plane since with $z_m:= 2^{-m}$ we have $\lim_{m\to \infty}z_m\cdot H\big(z_m\big)=a_{-1}$ and $\text{Re}\Big(z_m\cdot H\big(z_m\big)\Big) \gt 0$ for all $m$.  We also know $\frac{1}{a_{-1}}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{z}\cdot \frac{1}{H(z)}=  \lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{z}\cdot F\big(z\big)= \lim_{z\to 0}g\big(z\big) =\lambda$ so it suffices to show that $\lambda \in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}$, i.e. in effect that $\lambda = 1$ since WLOG $\big\vert \lambda\big \vert  =1$.
Suppose for contradiction that $\lambda$ is non-real, and in the closed upper half-plane (i.e. non-real residue in the lower half plane).  This is a sufficient contradiction -- if the residue were non-real and in the upper half-plane then that implies $\overline {H\big(\overline z\big)}$ has non-real residue in the lower half-plane, a contradiction per the following argument.  (Alternatively: just mimic the below argument for non-real $\lambda$ in the closed lower half-plane to directly get the result.)
$g$ is analytic and non-zero on $B\big(0,\delta\big)$, and $\text{Im}\big(\lambda\big)= d\gt 0$.  By continuity of $g$ we may set $\epsilon':= d$ and there is a $\delta'\in \big(0,\delta\big)$ such that $g\Big(B\big(0,\delta'\big)\Big)\subseteq B\big(\lambda, d\big)$, i.e. $g$ sends $B\big(0,\delta'\big)$ to the open upper half plane (points with positive imaginary part).  To finish, consider $w:= \frac{\delta'}{2}\cdot i$.  Then
$F\big(w\big) = w\cdot g\big(w\big) = \big\vert w\big\vert \cdot\exp\big(i\frac{\pi}{2}\big)\cdot \big \vert g(w)\big \vert\cdot \exp\big(i\cdot \theta\big)$
where $\text{Im}\big(g(w)\big)\gt 0\implies$ there is exactly satisfying $\theta \in \big(0,\pi\big)$ which is our choice for $\theta$. $\big[$Formally we may always increment $\theta$ by $n\cdot 2\pi$ for $n\in \mathbb Z$ but this is irrelevant here-- we choose the sole representative $\in\big(0,\pi\big)\big]$.
$\implies F\big(w\big) = \big\vert w\cdot g(w)\big\vert \cdot\exp\Big(i\big(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta\big)\Big)$ but
$\frac{\pi}{2}\lt\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta\lt \frac{3\pi}{2}\implies F(w)$ is in the open left half plane, a contradiction.

Thank you. It is going to take me a bit to digest this. I'll get back soon.

Unfortunately there's a lot of book-keeping to make this rigorous but in short what it it says is we know $n\big(\sigma_1,0\big) = \frac{k}{2}$ and we know $\Big \vert n\big(\gamma_1, 0\big)\Big \vert\leq \frac{1}{2}$ because the curve is trapped in the (closed) right half plane; the Key Lemma says one is a very good approximation of the other for $r$ small enough so $k$ must be small, i.e. $k\lt 2$.

I see that, but would like to follow the details as well since it seems like that understanding will help elsewhere. Also, the other part of statement (2) is about the residue being real and positive. Would rhetorical strategy for that be reverting back to $H$ from $F$, and using the residue theorem, or perhaps a different way that builds on this proof?

Still working through your proof and also thinking about how to approach the residue part of the statement. I am skeptical about how the latter is done in books such as the one I linked to in my original question. They say something like "in the vicinity of a pole the function behaves in very much the same way as the term in the partial fraction expansion with the highest multiplicity of the pole". I am not sure what "very much the same way" means. Do you think this approach makes sense?

It occurred to me that what your linked proof (sketch) does is in effect say for a small enough neighborhood we can ignore $F$ and just focus on $q$ and it does so without error bounding, etc. which is... lacking. The residue at zero, $a_{-1}$, should be equal to $\lambda^{-1}$ so the argument should reduce to $F(z)= z\cdot g(z)$ sends the closed right half plane to itself implies $\lambda \in \mathbb R_{\gt 0}$. In a sufficiently small neighborhood of $0$ we have a continuous $\text{Arg}_{-\pi}\circ g$ which I think should imply the result (i.e. non-real $\lambda$ yields a contradiction).

More technically on $B(0,\delta)$ for $\delta \gt 0$ small enough, which is simply connected, since $g$ is analytic and non-zero there, then in that set there is a branch of $\text{Log }g$.

I understand how the statement to be proved reduces to: $z g(z)$, with $g$ analytic and $g(0)\ne 0 \implies g(0)\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. But I don't understand how your last comment proves this. Also, could you please add this part to your answer, so that I can mark that as the answer to my question? Thank you.

Thank you for the addendum. I have accepted this answer. One more question --- what does "there exists a branch $\log \circ g$" mean?

It's a continuous function that satisfies $\exp\circ \text{log}\circ g = g$ in the domain; it means we can continuously (and consistently) define a choice of $\text{Log}\circ f$ in each point in $B\big(0,\delta\big)$. This shows up as part of a chain of equivalent ways of characterizing a simply connected domain at the end of a (demanding) intro to complex analysis. If you are interested: see the first 5 pages of chapter 11 of Beardon-- in general to compete the chain you need the Riemann Mapping Theorem (section 2 of chp 11) but you only need the easy directions here so RMT isn't required.

Ok I'll study up a bit and get back with any further questions

I just re-cut the addendum to use a simpler argument.  My instinct is to use a continuous choice of angle but it isn't really needed here.

Thank you. I am surprised that in the sketch proof that I linked, so much is pushed under the rug with just "very much the same way". Perhaps it is in preference of simplicity in an undergraduate engineering text, but I haven't found a rigorous proof anywhere else, hence my question.
